# Advanced Custom Fields Show After Password

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am new to ACF , so far I managed to add a new custom field and did this

[image]

[image]

Visitor can enter application no. and password to get its application statuses which admin has added.

I have used Repeater, it feels better working for me, Only 1 issue remaining, the get_field() is taking argument of (field name, post id) in my case I called it application_id in my above mentioned efforts. How can users search via the Application number which I will assign in integers format. So far I have done this (Ignore the inline css)

[image]

```
            <div class="entry-content">
            <form method="post">
              <label>Enter Application ID:</label>
              <input type="text" name="application_id">
              <label>Enter Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="application_pass">
              <center style="margin: 10px 0;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"></center>
            </form>
            <?php 
                $application_id = $_POST["application_id"];
                $entered_pass = $_POST["application_pass"];
                $client_name = get_field("client_name", $application_id);
                $program = get_field("program", $application_id);
                $password = get_field("password", $application_id);
                $application_status = get_field("application_status", $application_id);

                if ($entered_pass == $password) {
                    echo "  <div><span style='width:40%; float:left; font-weight: bold;'>Client Name:</span> <span style='width:60%; float:left;'>{$client_name} </span></div>
                            <div><span style='width:40%; float:left; font-weight: bold;'>Program Applied: </span> <span style='width:60%; float:left;'> {$program} </span></div>
                            <div><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Application Status:</span> <hr style='margin:3px;'>" ?>
                    <?php $x = 1;
                    if(get_field('application_status', $application_id)): ?>
                            <ul style="list-style: outside none none; font-weight: bold;">
                                <li style="width: 5%; float: left;">S#</li>
                                <li style="width: 78%; float: left;">Description</li>
                                <li style="width: 17%; float: left;">Date</li>
                            </ul>
                            <hr style='margin:3px;'>
                        <?php while(the_repeater_field('application_status', $application_id)): ?>
                            <ul style="list-style: outside none none;">
                                <li style="width: 5%; float: left;"><?php echo $x; $x++; ?></li>
                                <li style="width: 78%; float: left;"><?php the_sub_field('last_update'); ?></li>
                                <li style="width: 17%; float: left;"><?php the_sub_field('update_date'); ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php 
                    endif;
                    ?>

                <?php "</div>";} ?><!-- entered pass if -->

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: 1. Please only post one question, per, well, question. 2. Please show some effort of what you tried so it doesn't look like you're asking other people to do your work without you even having tried yourself.

Comment: I searched documentations and searched online. Managed this far. Can you please help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally read many articles and finally I got everything right. So here is the solution now for other people if they get caught up in same situation.

```
        <article id="" class="page type-page status-publish hentry">

        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title">Check Application Status</h1>   
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <form method="post">
              <label>Enter Application ID:</label>
              <input type="text" name="application_id">
              <label>Enter Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="application_pass">
              <center style="margin: 10px 0;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"></center>
            </form>
            <?php 
                $application_id = $_POST["application_id"];
                $entered_pass = $_POST["application_pass"];
            ?>
            <?php 
            $posts = get_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page'    => 1,
                'post_type'         => 'applications',
                'meta_query'    => array(
                                        'relation'      => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                'key'       => 'application_no',
                                                'value'     => $application_id
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                                'key'       => 'password',
                                                'value'     => $entered_pass
                                            )
                                    )
            ));
            ?>
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
                setup_postdata( $post )
                ?>
                <?php   $x = 1;
                        echo "Name: "; the_field("client_name"); echo "<br />";
                        echo "Application Number: "; the_field("application_no"); echo "<br />";
                        echo "Program: "; the_field("program"); echo "<br />";
                        echo "Application Status: "; 
                        ?>
                        <ul style="list-style: outside none none; font-weight: bold;">
                                            <li style="width: 5%; float: left;">S#</li>
                                            <li style="width: 78%; float: left;">Description</li>
                                            <li style="width: 17%; float: left;">Date</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <hr style='margin:3px;'>
                        <?php 
                        while(the_repeater_field('application_status')): ?>
                            <ul style="list-style: outside none none;">
                                <li style="width: 5%; float: left;"><?php echo $x; $x++; ?></li>
                                <li style="width: 78%; float: left;"><?php the_sub_field('last_update'); ?></li>
                                <li style="width: 17%; float: left;"><?php the_sub_field('update_date'); ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endwhile;
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs (never used flexible fields, only repeater fields, but look the same):

```
<?php

// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ):

     // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ) : the_row();

        if( get_row_layout() == 'paragraph' ):

            the_sub_field('text');

        elseif( get_row_layout() == 'download' ): 

            $file = get_sub_field('file');

        endif;

    endwhile;

else :

    // no layouts found

endif;

?>
```

Source: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/

Comment: Didn't get a clue from this example, by the way I had already read it before your post. But I switched my fields to Repeater, as it is better working for me :)

Comment: Well, you have to loop trought the rows, within the `have_posts()` loop, using `have_rows()`. Prepare the row using `the_row()` and get the sub field's data using `get_sub_field()`.